# $\| \|_1$and $\| \|_2$ are equivalent in a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $\| \|_1$and $\| \|_2$ be norms on $V$. Show that if $y \in V$ and $(x_1,x_2,..)$ is a sequence in $V$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n-y\|_1=0$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n-y\|_2=0$.

I have shown that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n-y\|_1=0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n-y\|_2=0$ but I don't know how to show the other part.

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwartz: $\left\|x\right\|_1\leq \sqrt{1^2+...+1^2}\cdot\left\|x\right\|_2=\sqrt{\operatorname{dim}(V)}\cdot\left\|x\right\|_2$

Comment: @olsen5 I don't think that, in this question, the index $2$ indicates that $||.||_2$ is the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @Thomas $\left\|x\right\|_1=\sum|x_i|=\sum 1\cdot|x_1|\leq \sqrt{1^2+...+1^2}\cdot \sqrt{\sum x_i^2}=\sqrt{\operatorname{dim}(V)}\cdot \left\|x\right\|_2$. Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: Either OP has misunderstood the meaning of $\|\cdot\|_1$ (as its typical interpretation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or similar sorts of spaces) or OP has basically done the problem but didn't realize it - this problem is symmetric, so if one could show one direction the the other direction follows.

Comment: @user340297 No, Both directions require proof, and don't follow one from the other. They follow from $\left\|x\right\|_2\leq\left\|x\right\|_1\leq\sqrt{\operatorname{dim}(V)}\cdot\left\|x\right\|_2$, for example.

Comment: @olsen5 How so? What OP proved is that if a sequence converges to a point in one norm, then it does in the other norm, and choices of these norms are arbitrary. What makes the other direction special?

Comment: @olsen5 I did understand what you are trying to hint at, but I also don't believe that $||.||_1$ denotes the $1$ - norm $\sum |x_i|$ -- what the OP is after is the statement that any two norms are equivalent on finite dimensional vector spaces (see the first sentence: "let ... be two norms"). And this is, in fact, a symmetric problem.

Comment: A proof can be found, for example, here: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf

Comment: Since norm equivalence is an equivalence relation, you may assume that one of the norms is, say $\|\cdot \||_1.$ One direction uses the continuity of the second norm via the triangle equality, and the other direction uses compactness of the unit ball.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of ambiguity regarding who $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ are, but if I understood well you want to show that any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent. So let $dimV=n$ and let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then the basis defines an isomorphism of $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, since any vector $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as $a_1e_1+\ldots+a_ne_n$ and so can be identified with $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. But then any norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_V$ on $V$ induces a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, given by $\Vert (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n}=\Vert v\Vert_V$. In particular, if you already know the result that states that any two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, you can deduce that it holds also on any finite dimensional vector space. If you don't know the result, in order to show that any two norms on $V$ are equivalent, it suffices to show that any norm is equivalent to the following one:
$$\Vert a_1e_1+\ldots+a_ne_n\Vert := \sum_{i=1}^n \vert a_i\vert$$
In order to do this, you need to use inequalities similar to the ones of @olsen5 comment.